# LoadLibrary: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, windows, dll, windows-server-2003

I need to extract some things about system process in a windows 2003 server (yeah, in 2019), I made that code in python, and compiled it with `auto_py_to_exe`

When I run the `.exe` file on the server, I recevbe an error saying `"LoadLibrary: The specified procedure could not be found."` referring to python37.dll

I try to compile like one directory (with the specific dll included), and I try to compile like one file, and I get the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAnDP.png).

Comment: Is *python37.dll* in the dir pointed by the error?

Comment: Yes sir, the python37.dll is in the dir

Answer (score 1):

There's a too big gap between *Python 3.7* and *Win 2003*. Looking at [[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) *Python 3.7* is not even listed there (as it's built with *VStudio 2017*). That, (and *Python* itself) will require / call functions that are not present in *Win 2003* system *.dll*s.

Here's an example. In the images below I opened 2 versions' (*2.7* and *3.7*) main *.dll* (*PYTHONCORE*) with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com):

[image: Img0]

As seen, both import a bunch of functions from *kernel32.dll*. But one difference is that *python37.dll* imports ***GetTickCount64***. According to [[MS.Learn]: GetTickCount64 function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64), the minimum *Server* version that supports it is *Win 2008*, meaning that **it won't work in *Win 2003***.

So, you'd have to go way back to *python 2.7* (tops). A number of years ago, I've built *Python **2.7.10*** with *VStudio **2010*** and it worked on *Win 2003* (and *XP SP 1*); most likely, this also applies to the newest (***2.7***) version.

Note that you'll also have to install all the packages that you use in your script (including *auto-py-to-exe*).

---

#### Update *#0*

I remembered (and just checked) that I have *Python **3.4.3*** on my *XP* (*SP 3*) *PC*. So, there's high chance that *Python 3* (prior to *3.5*) will work on *Win 2003* as well.

---

#### Update *#1*

Finally, I have some official statement: On [Python](https://www.python.org) official page, hovering the mouse over the "*Download*" button yields:

> **Note that Python 3.5+ *cannot* be used on Windows XP or earlier.**

or (even clearer):

[image: Img1]

Note that **it doesn't necessarily mean** that older versions are guaranteed to work. So, you'll need to do a bit of testing (I'd recommend installing *Python* and required packages on the target machine, and only when everything is successful, package everything).

---

#### Update *#2*

I mentioned that I've built a *Python2.7* version. *PsUtil* **was** part of it.

> ```py
> >>> import sys, platform, psutil
> >>> sys.version, sys.platform
> ('2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:08:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]', 'win32')
> >>> platform.platform()
> 'Windows-XP-5.1.2600-SP3'
> >>> psutil.__version__
> '3.1.1'
> ```

I didn't mention that I've built *PsUtil* from sources, but the prebuilt *.whl*s and also *Win* installers are available for download: [[PyPI]: psutil 3.1.1 - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/3.1.1/#files).

Related:

- [[SO]: Fatal error detected: error loading python dll 'python311.dll' (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75896857/4788546)

Comment: thanks for all, finally i used python 2.7.9 and py2exe, it solved, but PSutil its not compatible whit windows 2003 server .You know some alternative to PSutil to make wmi consultes like cpu usage?

Comment: Added in the answer: I used version *3.1.1*.