# R error that prevents me from executing library(tidyverse) and library(here)

Tags: r

So I installed the 'tidyverse' and 'here' packages from the Install Packages subheader under Tools, and when I try to run the following:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(here)
```

I receive an error stating:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/resha/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.2
```

Note that my working directory here is "C:/Users/resha/OneDrive/Desktop/STA238 R Documents/Tutorial 0 Files" which is different from 'C:/Users/resha/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll' that appears in the error message. Any help please?

Comment: What Windows version do you have? Have you recently installed RTools or updated R? Many things could cause this, from running an old version of Windows (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54188308) & [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a2f31a3d-8bf5-43a2-bdec-57c203dc7098/load-library-failedspecified-procedure-could-not-be-found?forum=vcgeneral)), to [PATH](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-shared-object-on-startup-in-rstudio-only/33107/4) or [RTools](https://community.rstudio.com/t/stat-package-will-not-load-after-installing-rtools/63265) issues

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two steps:

1. You need to rebuilt your packages under your current R version (your warning message says `"package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.2"`, so you have probably upgraded or downgraded R or used R on another PC with the same shared library on OneDrive?). So please run in your R console:

   ```
    update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)
   ```
2. You have your R library on a shared drive on your OneDrive, not your local PC, so:

   - make sure you have network connection
   - or make that folder accessible while offline (in your File Explorer right-click on `C:/Users/resha/OneDrive/Documents/R/` folder and select "Always keep on this device").