# Fatal error detected: error loading python dll 'python311.dll'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, auto-py-to-exe

I try to compile my python script with auto-py-to-exe, and it worked great (on Windows 10).
But when i tried to run the program on another computer (on Windows 7). At first there was an error there is not enough 'api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll'. When i downloaded this file and put it in base dir, occured new error: Error loading python dll 'python311.dll' and I don't know how to solve this problem.

I tried to search 'python311.dll' and download, but  didn't find.

Comment: the python.3.11 dll should be compiled with your app. I don't think python 3.11 supports windows 7.  In fact I don't think windows supports windows 7 anymore

Answer (score 0):

According to [[Python]: Python Releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows):

> **Note that Python 3.11.2 *cannot* be used on Windows 7 or earlier.**

This applies to other versions as well.

Alternatives:

##### 1. Upgrade to a newer (and **supported**) *Win* version (*v10*, *v11*, ...)

This is the **recommended** way.

According to [[MS]: End of support for Windows 7 and Windows 8.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-of-support?r=1) (**emphasis** is mine):

> After 10 years, **security updates and technical support for Windows 7 ended** on January 14, 2020.

And the corresponding image (as text is not copyable):

[image: Img0]

##### 2. Use an older *Python* version

This is more like a **workaround**.

As seen in the 1<sup>st</sup> *URL*, some *Python* versions (*v3.8*, *v3.7*, ...) still support *Windows 7*:

> **Note that Python 3.8.16 *cannot* be used on Windows XP or earlier.**

Needless to say that:

- Features introduced in the newer versions won't be available
- Some (3<sup>rd</sup>-party) modules might no longer support older *Python* versions as well. And less and less of them will continue supporting as time goes by

So, this is (or might become) neither manageable nor scalable (on the long run).

##### 3. Try building newer *Python* versions to run on *Windows 7*

Only listing this as a (remote) theoretical alternative (best to be **avoided**).
I'm not sure if it's possible (with / without modifying the code).

But even if it would be possible (you'd also need to make it publicly available somewhere, and not everyone will be willing to install it), maintenance problems would be **even greater than for *#2.***.

**Related**:

- [[SO]: LoadLibrary: The specified procedure could not be found (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54189912/4788546)